# How to import an external dataset into in a Moodle question?

Tags: r-exams

I would like to import an external dataset using `read.table()` (or any other function for reading files) and then randomize or sample over it. The file is stored in a subfolder within the parent folder that contains the exercises `*.rmd`. I am working within a  RStudio project. I tried placing the dataset in different levels of the folder structure. Using relative path did not work, but absolute paths did.

My folder structure is:

```
$home/project_name/exercises      # It contains the RMD files
$home/project_name/exercises/data # It contains data files that I want to process
$home/project_name/datasets       # this folder could eventually contain the dataset I want to process
```

To make this code more portable, I would like to know o the manage relative paths within `*.Rmd` for the knitting process.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your problem with the answer below? If not please comment so that I can refine the answer. If yes, then please accept the answer so that the problem appears as solved here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The exercises are copied to a temporary directory and processed there. Hence, the easiest option is to copy these files to the temporary directory using `include_supplement("file.csv")`. By default this assumes that the `file.csv` is in the same directory that the exercise itself resides in. If it is in a subdirectory you can use `include_supplement("file.csv", recursive = TRUE)` and then subdirectories are searched recursively for `file.csv`.

After using `include_supplement()`, the copied file is available locally and can be processed with `read.table()` or also included in the exercise as a supplementary file. See http://www.R-exams.org/templates/Rlogo/ for a worked example. However, note that the `Rlogo` template explicitly specifies the directory from which the file should be copied. This is not necessary if that directory is the same as the exercise or a subdirectory.